# No body available of type: com.mongodb.DBObject

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, apache-camel

I have camel route which is reading a file and has to insert the content of the file in mongoDB. I have successfully read the file but could not insert the content it in to mongoDB. It is throwing an exception `org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: com.mongodb.DBObject` Please have a look.

**Console Log**

> Message History
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor
>   Elapsed (ms) [route1            ] [route1            ]
>   [file://C://workspace//EmailResponseAutomation//response//
>   ] [         2] [route1            ] [convertBodyTo1    ]
>   [convertBodyTo[com.mongodb.DBObject]
>   ] [         2]
>
> ### Stacktrace
>
> org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type:
>   com.mongodb.DBObject but has value:
>   GenericFile[C:\workspace\EmailResponseAutomation\response\SampleEmailResponseFile.txt]
>   of type: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFile on:
>   SampleEmailResponseFile.txt. Caused by: No type converter available to
>   convert from type: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFile to the
>   required type: com.mongodb.DBObject with value
>   GenericFile[C:\workspace\EmailResponseAutomation\response\SampleEmailResponseFile.txt].
>   Exchange[ID-XAV-101001260-52594-1521452849077-0-12]. Caused by:
>   [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type
>   converter available to convert from type:
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFile to the required type:
>   com.mongodb.DBObject with value
>   GenericFile[C:\workspace\EmailResponseAutomation\response\SampleEmailResponseFile.txt]]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:107)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.ConvertBodyProcessor.process(ConvertBodyProcessor.java:91)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:468)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
>   [camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)
>   [camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
>   [camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
>   [camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]    at
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:454)
>   [camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]    at
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:226)
>   [camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]    at
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:190)
>   [camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]    at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:175)
>   [camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]    at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:102)
>   [camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   [na:1.8.0_102]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
>   [na:1.8.0_102]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>   [na:1.8.0_102]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
>   [na:1.8.0_102]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [na:1.8.0_102]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [na:1.8.0_102]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   [na:1.8.0_102] Caused by:
>   org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter
>   available to convert from type:
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFile to the required type:
>   com.mongodb.DBObject with value
>   GenericFile[C:\workspace\EmailResponseAutomation\response\SampleEmailResponseFile.txt]
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:198)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:105)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   ... 19 common frames omitted

**Camel Route**

```
@Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("file://workspace//EmailResponseAutomation//response//")
                .convertBodyTo(com.mongodb.DBObject.class)
                .to("mongodb:myDb?database=email_response&collection=emailResponse&operation=save");
    }

    @Bean
    public Mongo myDb() {
        return new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27017));
    }
```

Comment: Try with a newer version of Camel

Comment: I solved this issue with `from(SOURCE).process(new Processor() {
   @Override
   public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    final EmailResponseModel erm = new EmailResponseModel();
    erm.setEmail(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
    exchange.getIn().setBody(erm, DBObject.class);
   }
  }).to(DESTINATION);`