# POST Request using Apache Camel and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, apache-camel, http-post

I am following this example online: https://dzone.com/articles/apache-camel-mongodb-component-example?fbclid=IwAR0u8VuBNWmJtIyz7RRF9iYpYD9XTHmqorMopfbxQz884HO6QSkEjqhyXsY. When I get to the steps of trying to insert `{name:"Anne"}` into my database by making a `POST` request using Postman, I keep getting this error:

```
org.apache.camel.component.mongodb.CamelMongoDbException: 
MongoDB operation = insert, 
Body is not conversible to type DBObject nor List<DBObject>.
```

The content-type I have set is raw (text).

I have tried adding `.convertBodyTo("DBObject.class")` after the `from`, but that gave me this error

```
org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: 
No body available of type: com.mongodb.DBObject but has value:
org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache@7e51f45 of type:
org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache on: Message: 
[Body is instance of org.apache.camel.StreamCache]. 
Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type:
org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache to the required type:
com.mongodb.DBObject with value
org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache@7e51f45.
```

```
    public class CamelMongoRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure()throws Exception{
                from("jetty:http://localhost:8181/mongoSelect")
                .to("mongodb:myDb?database=customerdb&collection=customer&operation=findAll");
                from("jetty:http://localhost:8181/mongoInsert")
                .to("mongodb:myDb?database=customerdb&collection=customer&operation=insert");
                }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried that, but it gives me another error: 'org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: com.mongodb.DBObject but has value: org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache@440e708a of type: org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache on: Message: [Body is instance of org.apache.camel.StreamCache].'

Comment: Sorry about that. I have updated the question.

Comment: you would have to write a simple Processor like shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49360069/no-body-available-of-type-com-mongodb-dbobject#comment85755135_49360069